# Navigating between tab bar controller screens in different navigation controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

First of all sorry if I'm explaining this badly, I've re-read my question several times and I can't figure out how a great way to explain the problem. Please let me know if you have any other questions...

My app has a layout that requires the screens to be embedded in both a tab bar controller and navigation controller. I've got it set up so that it works for the most part, however I'm running into some problems navigating from one navigation controller/tab to another - I have one navigation controller for one tab (where the user selects an image to upload), and a second navigation controller for the screens in the second tab. Here is what it looks like in storyboard:

[image]

The problem I have is that once the user selects a photo to post in the "upper" navigation controller (the "right" tab) and hits "post", I navigate to the newly updated feed (which is within the other tab) with:

```
                let feedController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "feedVC") as! FeedViewController
                feedController.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
                self.navigationController?.pushViewController(feedController, animated: true)
```

And while the screen and updated feed appear correctly, I am still within the "right" tab, when the feed should be in the "left" tab.

My question is, how do I correctly navigate to the other navigation controller, and be put back within the correct tab?

Comment: Maybe `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 1` would help? Switching tabs instead of pushing a new controller onto the first tab's navigation stack?

Comment: I tried adding `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0` before the push and while it did put me back to the correct tab, the feed appeared as it was before I selected an image to upload - the updated feed was still in the "second" tab. After uploading an image I was to leave that second tab entirely.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the flow. Could you refresh the original feed when it appears after switching tabs, and don't push it elsewhere? (Unless there's a reason the original in the first tab needs to stay un-updated.) Or do you want to push the new feed view on top of the old one? In which case switching tabs and then putting the code you already provided for the push in the feed view controller could do the trick.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm finding it hard to explain. Basically I have two tabs, left and right. The left tab has the feed, and a few other windows. The only thing the right tab has is the upload controller, where you can select an image to upload, then tap "post". At that point you should be taken out of the right tab and back to left tab, to the newly updated feed. However with the way I have it now, when I upload an image, the updated feed is shown in the upload tab instead of in the feed tab.

Comment: If I tap the right (upload) tab icon twice again after all this it returns back to the way it should, and likewise if I do the same to the left (feed) tab icon, it shows the correct updated feed and all is back to normal. I just don't want to have to tap each tab icon twice after I upload an image for the screens to show up correctly.

Comment: It sounds like what you're describing is just not pushing anything (so getting rid of that code entirely) when tapping "post" and *only* switching tabs programatically. Then I think you just need to refresh the view in the first tab (maybe in the feed view controller's viewWillAppear method)--if I understood correctly.

Comment: @Samantha That worked! Feel free to post an answer and I'll select it it you want. I just removed the `push` code and only kept `self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0` in the upload function. And I had the code to fetch the images for the feed in `viewDidLoad` in my feed controller so I added a `viewWillAppear` like you said and put that code in there instead. Now there's more of a "flicker" as the images load in the feed when the the page is presented, but it'll work. Thanks a lot for the suggestions!

Comment: Posted it as an answer--glad it worked!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can switch tabs instead of pushing a new view controller onto the current tab's navigation stack using `tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`. This should take you back to the original feed page with no need for any of the push code.

In order to update it with the new post, you'll need to refresh the data when it appears by overriding the view controller's `viewWillAppear` method to re-fetch the data and reload the collection view.